# How to avoid consequences of sandbox security token refresh - Eclipse IDE projects

Tags: security, security-token

Every time after sandbox refresh, security token is expired. So this causes necessity of creation of new security token and sending it to your email. Then you have to update that information in Force.com IDE in your project settings.

This is quite nauseous.

I have found a solution for developers who work from office and whose company has static public IP address.

Comment: I believe future versions of force.com IDE will start using OAuth which will make this a non-issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically I have written about this in my blog about Salesforce: http://patlatus.wordpress.com/2014/08/29/salesforce-use-force-com-without-security-token/

Also shortly explain solution here.

So, if you have static public IP address, you could just update your security settings to include your public IP address to list of known Trusted IP Range and then you will not have to include Security Token at all.

First of all, you have to know your IP address. If you don’t know it, just visit any of public services which show it to you like http://whatismyipaddress.com/ or http://www.whatismyip.com/ or http://www.whatsmyip.org/.

Next you have to go to Security Controls \ Network Access under Administer or Administration Setup.
Then you have to click New button and input your public IP address twice as start and end of IP range.

[image: Trusted IP Range]

Also to access this list you could have just remove everything after “salesforce.com/” in address line and input there “05G” and press enter. So, for example, if one of Salesforce instances I use is located on second European server, then my link is https://eu2.salesforce.com/05G/
If you add instead 05G/e you will get directly to edit page. So, for my Salesforce instance on second European server the link would be https://eu2.salesforce.com/05G/e. This works also on sandboxes https://cs14.salesforce.com/05G/e.

Hope this would help other people to save their time.

Answer (score 3):

Security tokens will match what's in production after a sandbox refresh. To avoid people needing to update their credentials after a refresh you'll need to continue to use the production password / security token in sandboxes after a refresh.

Bear in mind, once you have a sandbox, if you reset the security token or change the password you'll then be out of sync with production. At that point the next refresh will trash that security token (along with everything else in that sandbox) and start fresh again with what's in production.